# Facing AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused error, unable to identify the root cause

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am encountering an issue when making a POST request using WebClient. I have a class that creates the WebClient bean as follows:

```
@Component
public class WebClientProvider {

  @Bean
  public WebClient provideWebClient(
      @Autowired TcpClient tcpClient, @Value("${messaging.publisherHost}") String publisherHost) {
    return WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(publisherHost)
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient)))
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .build();
  }
}
```

And I am using this WebClient to make a POST request:

```
public String postMail(EmailRequest emailRequest, String url) {
    return webClient
                .post()
                .uri(url)
                .body(Mono.just(emailRequest), EmailRequest.class)
                .exchange()
                .block()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
}
```

I retrieve the messaging.publisherHost value from the application.yml file, and its value is in the form of http://messaging-publisher-rt:8080. When I deploy a new version of the application, I get an "AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: messaging-publisher-rt/10.0.1.52:8080" error. The new version only includes bug fixes without significant changes. Reverting to the old version resolves the issue. Both projects are running on the same EC2 instance. I'm having trouble identifying the root cause of this problem.

Can anyone help me understand why this exception occurs after deploying a new version, and how I can resolve it?